# What are the recent developments of GW@BSE to simulate the excited properties of materials?

Tags: density-functional-theory, one-topic-per-answer, td-dft, gw-bse, excited-states

[A twin question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/what-are-the-recent-developments-of-tddft-to-simulate-the-excitated-properteis-o) related to the TDDFT method is asked in another post. But any comparisons between both methods in recent developments are welcome.

The [time-dependent density functional theory (TDDFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-dependent_density_functional_theory#:%7E:text=Time%2Ddependent%20density%2Dfunctional%20theory,as%20electric%20or%20magnetic%20fields.) and the many-body perturbation theory (GW@BSE) methods are considered as the two most popular and successful methods to describe the excited-stated properties of materials. In fact, both methods have been reviewed in [this classical paper published in Review of Morden Physics](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.74.601). From that almost twenty years have passed. What are the recent developments of the GW@BSE method? And what are the current challenges to simulate real materials with the GW@BSE method? As far as I know, the [BerkeleyGW GROUP](https://berkeleygw.org/) and [Yambo GROUP](http://www.yambo-code.org/) have successfully implemented the framework of the GW@BSE method based on plane-wave DFT calculations. Are there any packages to realize this method, especially without dependence on plane-wave DFT?

Comment: I am not an expert on the question, but there are several different implementations both for plane waves and localized basis. The difference I have found were the different approximations implemented: GW is extremely slow and poorly scaling, so all kind of tricks trying to improve those bottlenecks. Sime codes that include GW, generally several different approximations each (I am not sure BSE): VASP, Turbomole, cp2k

Answer (score 8):

As one of the members of the [Yambo group](https://www.yambo-code.eu) I can answer for the developments, in the [Yambo code](https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-648X/ab15d0), in particular related to GW and BSE. One important aspect is the code optimization, and the connected porting on GPU cards (see the [Max Centre of excellence](http://www.max-centre.eu)). Work was done in optimizing GW and BSE for 2D materials, see for example the [RIM-W method](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.11946) and the [multi-plasmon pole approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01532); adding [support for spin-orbit](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.103.155152) coupling both in GW and BSE; and computing finite momentum exciton dispersion, which, for example, opens the way to compute [exciton-phonon coupling](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.107401).

The modelling of excitons out of equilibrium is one of the new subjects of interest for the community. Starting from the formulation of [the real-time BSE](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.245110), the recent developments include the study of [exciton-phonon coupling in photoluminescence](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.187401), the signature of excitons in [ARPES](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevMaterials.5.083803) and [transient Absorption spectroscopy](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12241).

Going beyond what is in the Yambo code, recent ongoing activity on exciton dynamics both [numerical](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/accepted/af071J0cKe918f06407b54657dc2510775de52c7b) and [theoretical](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.128.016801). Also very recent theoretical works include the use of MBPT to go from electron-phonon [to the modelling of polarons](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.246403), and ongoing activity to capture exciton-polaron interaction. It is of course not exhaustive, and mostly focused on (part of) my research activity, with also few new recent works that I like on the subject.

Finally a short comment for GW and BSE not in plane wave. There are packages, such as for example the [Fiesta](http://perso.neel.cnrs.fr/xavier.blase/fiesta/) code of the [MolGW](http://www.molgw.org/) code focused on isolated systems, and for extended systems code such as [Elk](https://elk.sourceforge.io/) and [Exciting](http://exciting.wikidot.com/). The list is not at all exhaustive. The [GW100 initiative](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.5b00453) is also a good reference for many other codes.